# What does the @ operator do in SAS

Tags: sas

Not able to search for the @ parameter in the search engines or the syntax.

What does the @ operator do in SAS? I am not able to find any references to it in the operators list as well: https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000780367.htm

```
data dsfa.asdfa;
   infile asdfsadf;
   input @1 sdfs $12. @14 sdlfsda $10 sdlfsd $1.;
run;
```

Comment: It's not an operator. Look at the INPUT statement in the documentation to see what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an operator, it's part of the INPUT statement and documented within the INPUT statement. There are trailing @ or @@ and then ones that come before variable names. In that case, it's telling SAS which column to read data from.

> @n moves the pointer to column n.

[Here's the link to the docs](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=n0oaql83drile0n141pdacojq97s.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

Answer (score 0):

In format input method we can read data values from raw data files by using 3 methods
1)Column Skip pointer(+n)
2)Column hold pointer(@n)
3)Column range(n.)

So in the below code:
input @1 sdfs $12. @14 sdlfsda $10 sdlfsd $1.;

@1 means you are instructing SAS to read from first column upto 12 characters length
@14 means you are instructing SAS to read from 14th column upto 10 characters length
Note: @n means column number to start reading